# gpsLocation with androidservice in fulltime in DELPHI

Tags: android, delphi, background, gps

Try this code, but my application closes, I want to get the GPS location every so often but it does not work for now I'm visualizing
 with udp client.

```
type
  TAndroidServiceDM = class(TAndroidService)
    function AndroidServiceStartCommand(const Sender: TObject;
      const Intent: JIntent; Flags, StartId: Integer): Integer;
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FLocationManager: JLocationManager;
    FLocationManagerService: JObject;
    FLocationListener: JLocationListener;

  protected

  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  AndroidServiceDM: TAndroidServiceDM;

implementation

{ %CLASSGROUP 'FMX.Controls.TControl' }

uses AndroidApi.JNI.App;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure send_udp(ip: string; puerto: Integer; datos: string);
var
  send_udp: TIdUDPClient;
begin
  send_udp := TIdUDPClient.Create(nil);
  send_udp.Host := ip;
  send_udp.Port := puerto;
  send_udp.Send(datos);
  send_udp.Free;
end;

function TAndroidServiceDM.AndroidServiceStartCommand(const Sender: TObject;
  const Intent: JIntent; Flags, StartId: Integer): Integer;
  var
  iter:JIterator;
  location : JLocation;
begin

  Result := TJService.JavaClass.START_STICKY;
  FLocationManagerService := TAndroidHelper.Context.getSystemService(
    TJContext.JavaClass.LOCATION_SERVICE);
  FLocationManager := TJLocationManager.Wrap(
    (FLocationManagerService as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);

  if FLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(
    TJLocationManager.JavaClass.GPS_PROVIDER) then
  begin
    FLocationListener := TJLocationListener.Create;
      FLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(TJLocationManager.JavaClass.GPS_PROVIDER,
        0, 0, FLocationListener, TJLooper.JavaClass.getMainLooper);


  end;
  location := FLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(TJLocationManager.JavaClass.GPS_PROVIDER);

   send_udp('127.0.0.1',5555,'Servicio Iniciado'+location.getLatitude.ToString);

end;

end.
```

if someone can help me with this code or some other to send the gps location

I need to send the position every 10 minutes.

Comment: Can you elaborate "it does not work"? What kind of failure? Are there any error messages etc?

Comment: You're calling getLastKnownLocation only when the service starts. You'll need to use a timer (not an FMX timer, since they don't work in a service), e.g: https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=915936, and start it when the service is created. When the screen is locked, you'll also need to use a WakeLock. I've been working on a Delphi solution for obtaining location updates in a service that includes all this, however it's not quite ready yet; maybe in a couple of weeks.

Answer (score 0):

The 1 part that's missing from the code is your `FLocationListener`. You need to implement that! Once you do, the `onLocationChanged` function will be call(ed back) when the phone moves. The other part is specifying the minimum reporting frequency and the minimum time and minimum distance (10 seconds and 30 meters in my code). 
There is no need for timers or loops, not even in a Service.

Here is some of my code from my Delphi Android Service project (just some of the  important parts) I hope you can place them correctly in your project because I don't want to paste my whole project in here!

```
  TLocationListener = class;
```

...

```
  locationListener: TLocationListener;
```

...

```
TLocationListener = class(TJavaLocal, JLocationListener)
private
  [weak] FParent : TMainService;
public
  constructor Create(AParent : TMainService);
  procedure onLocationChanged(location: JLocation); cdecl;
  procedure onProviderDisabled(provider: JString); cdecl;
  procedure onProviderEnabled(provider: JString); cdecl;
  procedure onStatusChanged(provider: JString; status: Integer; extras: JBundle); cdecl;
end;
```

...

```
procedure TMainService.StartAndroidGPS;
var
  LocationManagerService: JObject;
  location: JLocation;
begin

  if not Assigned(FLocationManager) then
  begin
    LocationManagerService :=
      TAndroidHelper.Context.getSystemService(TJContext.JavaClass.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    FLocationManager := TJLocationManager.Wrap(
      (LocationManagerService as ILocalObject).GetObjectID
      );
    if not Assigned(locationListener) then
      locationListener := TLocationListener.Create(self);
  end;

   FLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(TJLocationManager.JavaClass.GPS_PROVIDER,
          Round(10 * 1000), 30, locationListener,
            TJLooper.JavaClass.getMainLooper);

  // just to get started, ask the GPS for the Last Known Position (if any)
  location := FLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(TJLocationManager.JavaClass.GPS_PROVIDER);
  LocationisChanged(location);

end;
```

...

```
procedure TMainService.StopAndroidGPS;
begin
  if Assigned(locationListener) then
    FLocationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
end;
```

...

```
{ TLocationListener }

constructor TLocationListener.Create(AParent: TMainService);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FParent := AParent;
end;

procedure TLocationListener.onLocationChanged(location: JLocation);
begin
  FParent.LocationisChanged(location);
end;
```

...

```
procedure TMainService.LocationisChanged(location: JLocation);
var
  lc: TLocationCoord2D;
begin
  // do whatever you need to do with the location here, for example:
  lc := TLocationCoord2D.Create(location.getLatitude, location.getLongitude))
end;
```