# How to implement Androidapi::Jni::Location with C++Builder?

Tags: android, delphi, gps, java-native-interface, c++builder

I'm writing my first Android app with FireMonkey/C++Builder 11, and I have some issue with implementing the `LocationListener` function described in the following Delphi GPS Android example:

[gpsLocation with androidservice in fulltime in DELPHI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48178164/)

The Delphi example code is:

```pascal
procedure TMainService.StartAndroidGPS;
var
  LocationManagerService: JObject;
  location: JLocation;
begin
  if not Assigned(FLocationManager) then
  begin
    LocationManagerService := TAndroidHelper.Context.getSystemService(TJContext.JavaClass.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    FLocationManager := TJLocationManager.Wrap(
      (LocationManagerService as ILocalObject).GetObjectID
    );
    if not Assigned(locationListener) then
      locationListener := TLocationListener.Create(self);
  end;
       
  FLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(TJLocationManager.JavaClass.GPS_PROVIDER,
     Round(10 * 1000), 30, locationListener,
     TJLooper.JavaClass.getMainLooper);
       
  // just to get started, ask the GPS for the Last Known Position (if any)
  location := FLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(TJLocationManager.JavaClass.GPS_PROVIDER);
  LocationisChanged(location);  
end;
```

The `TLocationListener` is defined as follow:

```pascal
TLocationListener = class(TJavaLocal, JLocationListener)
private
  [weak] FParent : TMainService;
public
  constructor Create(AParent : TMainService);
  procedure onLocationChanged(location: JLocation); cdecl;
  procedure onProviderDisabled(provider: JString); cdecl;
  procedure onProviderEnabled(provider: JString); cdecl;
  procedure onStatusChanged(provider: JString; status: Integer; extras: JBundle); cdecl;
end;
```

And it is created with:

```pascal
locationListener: TLocationListener;
```

I'm struggling with implementing the `Listener` function in C++Builder.

My main code is:

```cpp
void __fastcall THeaderFooterwithNavigation::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
{
    if(FLocationManager==NULL)
    {
        _di_JLocationManager LocationManager;    
        _di_JObject LocationManagerService = SharedActivityContext()->getSystemService(TJContext::JavaClass->LOCATION_SERVICE);
                
        FLocationManager = TJLocationManager::Wrap((_di_IJavaInstance)LocationManagerService);
                
        FLocationManager->requestLocationUpdates(TJLocationManager::JavaClass->GPS_PROVIDER,10000,10,locationListener,TJLooper::JavaClass->getMainLooper());
    }
}
```

I have declared the `TLocationListener` in the header file as follows:

```cpp
class TLocationListener : public TJavaLocal, JLocationListener
{
public :
    __fastcall TLocationListener();
    void __fastcall onLocationChanged(JLocation *location);
    void __fastcall onProviderDisabled(JString provider);
    void __fastcall onProviderEnabled(JString provider);
    void __fastcall onStatusChanged(JString provider,int status, JBundle extras);
    __fastcall ~TLocationListener();
};
```

However, I have no idea how to implement `[weak] FParent : TMainService;` with C++Builder (`THeaderFooterwithNavigation` in my case).

I create the `locationListener` with

```cpp
locationListener = new TLocationListener::TLocationListener();
```

But I get the following error:

> [bccaarm Error] HeaderFooterFormwithNavigation.cpp(311): allocating an object of abstract class type 'TLocationListener::TLocationListener'

And I get the error below when `locationListener` is called by the function `FLocationManager->requestLocationUpdates`

> [bccaarm Error] HeaderFooterFormwithNavigation.cpp(1143): cannot cast 'TLocationListener' to its private base class 'Androidapi::Jni::Location::JLocationListener'

I have converted other Delphi JNI code examples into C++Builder without any issue, but I cannot see how to implement the GPS listener function properly in C++.

PS: I m aware about `TLocationSensor` but I need to get extra information only available through the `Android.JNI.Location` lib.

Comment: `locationListener = new TLocationListener::TLocationListener();` should be `locationListener = new TLocationListener;`, and `class TLocationListener : public TJavaLocal, JLocationListener` should be `class TLocationListener : public TJavaLocal, public JLocationListener`, and `(_di_IJavaInstance)LocationManagerService` should be `di_ILocalObject(LocationManagerService)->GetObjectID()`. As for the abstract error, it should be telling you WHY the type is abstract, ie which abstract method wasn't implemented.

Comment: Thank you for your ultra fast and useful reply. 

TLocationListener is now defined as:

`class TLocationListener : public TJavaLocal, public JLocationListener
  {
  public :
 void onLocationChanged(_di_JLocation location);
 void onProviderDisabled(_di_JString provider);
 void onProviderEnabled(_di_JString provider);
 void onStatusChanged(_di_JString provider,int status,_di_JBundle extras);
 HRESULT QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void ** ppvObject);
 ULONG AddRef();
 ULONG Release();
  };`

Comment: The implementation of the virtual functions are done with empty functions for the moment :
`void TLocationListener::onLocationChanged(_di_JLocation location) {}`

I don't have any compiler error anymore however my app get immediately stuck when I launch it on my phone with or without calling `locationListener=new TLocationListener`;

The only way to not get stuck is to not call `locationListener=new TLocationListener` AND use * instead for any java types used in the functions
eg: `void TLocationListener::onLocationChanged(_di_JLocation *location)`

Comment: I clearly don't implement the functions properly!

Comment: Do not use `*` with `_di_` types in C++. They already hold a pointer internally. So, for example, `location: JLocation` in Delphi is equivalent to `JLocation* location` or `_di_JLocation location` in C++. Note the former does not participate in reference counting, while the latter one does. In any case, if your code is still having problems even if you don't create the `TLocationListener` object, then the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have corrected the TLocationListener class and it has solved the previous issue but I bumped in a new problem.  
I have declared `_di_JLocationManager FLocationManager;` and `_di_JObject LocationManagerService;` as public in my main form then I call the following functions **before** instanciate the TLocationListener.
`LocationManagerService = SharedActivityContext()->getSystemService(TJContext::JavaClass->LOCATION_SERVICE);
FLocationManager = TJLocationManager::Wrap(_di_ILocalObject(LocationManagerService)->GetObjectID());`

Comment: but the wrap function generates the following error : `Mangle error: the type 'JlocationListener' is invalid for describing a Java class type. The former must be an interface annotated with the JavaSignature attribute`
I can not figure what is wrong as the C++ implementation of the wrap function is very similar to the working delphi implementation of the wrap function.

Comment: Did you define the `TJLocationManager` class yourself in your own code, or are you using a definition provided by Embarcadero's RTL?

Comment: I use the embarcadero definition. It is defined in "Androidapi.JNI.Location.hpp'
```class PASCALIMPLEMENTATION TJLocationManager : public Androidapi::Jnibridge::TJavaGenericImport__2<_di_JLocationManagerClass,_di_JLocationManager>
{
 typedef Androidapi::Jnibridge::TJavaGenericImport__2<_di_JLocationManagerClass,_di_JLocationManager> inherited; 
public:
 /*TObject.Create*/ inline __fastcall TJLocationManager() : Androidapi::Jnibridge::TJavaGenericImport__2<_di_JLocationManagerClass,_di_JLocationManager>() {}
 /*TObject.Destroy*/ inline __fastcall virtual ~TJLocationManager() {} 
};```

Comment: Sorry, my bad.  The error message is complaining about `JLocationListener`, not `JLocationManager`. Do you have a `Wrap()` call that is trying to access `JLocationListener`? What is the *exact* line that is throwing the `'JlocationListener' is invalid for describing a Java class type` error? I'm pretty sure that Embarcdero's `[JavaSignature]` attribute is not usable in C++, only in Delphi. You may have to re-implement your listener in Delphi and then add it to your C++ project.

Comment: The error message is displayed when  `FLocationManager = TJLocationManager::Wrap(_di_ILocalObject(LocationManagerService)->GetObjectID());` is called. There is no other Wrap function called in my code.

Comment: I just don't see how that code shown can produce that error. You are likely going to have to contact Embarcadero for further help.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help! I will contact Embarcadero for further explanation, meantime I will try to implement the function via Delphi as you suggested.