# How to implement Androidapi::Jni::Location with Delphi/C++Builder?

Tags: android, delphi, gps, java-native-interface, c++builder

My previous attempt to implement Androidapi::Jni::Location with C++ builder finished in a dead end.
([Full story here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73348562/how-to-implement-androidapijnilocation-with-cbuilder?noredirect=1#comment129568446_73348562))

I'm trying now to implement the JNI location listener in a Delphi function which is called by my main C++ form as previously suggested.

I have written two simple examples to test this solution. One in C++ building calling the pascal function for creating the listener and a second example in pure delphi.

Both examples start well however after few seconds, when the listener launch the onLocationChanged, both apps crash without any error message. I can not figure why. Both have the **fine location permission** enabled.

Here is the "pure" Delphi version of the code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Memo.Types,
  FMX.ScrollBox, FMX.Memo, FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls,
  Androidapi.JNI.Provider ,Androidapi.Helpers, Androidapi.JNI.App,
  FMX.Helpers.Android, Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText, Androidapi.JNI.Os,
  Androidapi.JNI.Location, Androidapi.JNIBridge, Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    FLocationManager: JLocationManager;
    FLocationManagerService: JObject;
    locationListener: JLocationListener;
  end;

  TLocationListener = class(TJavaLocal, JLocationListener)
private
  [weak] FParent : TForm1;

  constructor Create(AParent : TForm1);
  procedure onLocationChanged(location: JLocation); cdecl;
  procedure onProviderDisabled(provider: JString); cdecl;
  procedure onProviderEnabled(provider: JString); cdecl;
  procedure onStatusChanged(provider: JString; status: Integer; extras: JBundle); cdecl;
public
end;


var
  Form1: TForm1;
  flg_JNI_new_loc  : Boolean;
  JNI_lat, JNI_lon : Double;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LocationManagerService: JObject;
  location: JLocation;
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Append('Starting JNI GPS listener service...');

  if not Assigned(FLocationManager) then
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Append('FLocation Manager not assigned');
    LocationManagerService := TAndroidHelper.Context.getSystemService(TJContext.JavaClass.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    FLocationManager := TJLocationManager.Wrap((LocationManagerService as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);
    if not Assigned(locationListener) then
     begin
     Memo1.Lines.Append('locationListener not assigned');
     locationListener := TLocationListener.Create(self);
     end
    else
     Memo1.Lines.Append('locationListener already assigned');
   end
   else
    Memo1.Lines.Append('FLocation Manager already assigned');

   FLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(TJLocationManager.JavaClass.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 30, locationListener,TJLooper.JavaClass.getMainLooper);
   Memo1.Lines.Append('Done');

end;

procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
if Assigned(locationListener) then
    FLocationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
end;


procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
if flg_JNI_new_loc = True then
begin
  flg_JNI_new_loc  := false;
  Memo1.Lines.Append('New loc '+Format('%.2f',  [JNI_lat])+' '+Format('%.2f', [JNI_lon]));
  end  ;
end;

//..............................................................................
{ TLocationListener }
constructor TLocationListener.Create(AParent: TForm1);
begin
  inherited Create;
  flg_JNI_new_loc := false;
  FParent := AParent;
end;


procedure TLocationListener.onLocationChanged(location: JLocation);
begin

  JNI_lat:=location.getLatitude;
  JNI_lon:=location.getLongitude;
  flg_JNI_new_loc:=true;
end;


procedure TLocationListener.onProviderDisabled(provider: JString);
begin

end;

procedure TLocationListener.onProviderEnabled(provider: JString);
begin

end;

procedure TLocationListener.onStatusChanged(provider: JString; status: Integer; extras: JBundle);
begin
end;

end.
```

The Listener is created when I click on the Button1. After one sec (with the phone outdoor), when onLocationChanged is supposed to be called, the app crash.

I'm using the embarcadero trial version (11.1.5 ?)  and my phone runs Android PIE

Any idea why my code does not work?

Comment: If you're using the trial, the definition for JLocationListener is missing an overload for Android 12, namely: `procedure onLocationChanged(locations: JList); overload; cdecl;` (the other onLocationChanged will need to be marked as `overload` as well)

Comment: Thank you Dave. Thanks to your hint, I found a more detailed explanation how to modify ```JLocationListener``` and ```TLocationListener```  in ***Androidapi.JNI.location.pas*** and ***System.Android.Sensors.pas*** to correct ```TLocationSensor``` compatibility issue between Delphi 11.1 + Android 11/12. This solved also my LocationListener implementation in C++/Delphi. The correction is described in spanish [here](https://delphidesdecero.com/tlocationsensor/tlocationsensor-gran-error-en-delphi-11-solucion-en-delphi-11-1/) I don't speak spanish but the explanatation is easy to understand.